# I need help to implement a combo-box which refines searches based on user query searches using PHP

Tags: php

Ok so I have implemented a search algorithm which allows users to search for mobile phones. But I would like to implement a feature at the top of my search which allows users to refine there search. For example, they can select a value from a d combo box which allows users to refine their search by [Lowest Price, Highest Price, Most Relevant] and so on. I would like to implement this in my PHP code.

The HTML code:

```
<form method="post">   
<div class="text-right">
    <select name="refineSearch" readonly="readonly" style="height: 22px">
<option value="Lowest">Lowest Price First</option>
<option value="Higeset">Higest Price First</option>
    </select>   </div>
 <div id="query_results"></div>

 </form>
```

sql code

```
SELECT * FROM Phone WHERE UPPER (Phone_Name) LIKE ('%$search%') &&        Sale_Type = 'Sell' &&  Phone_Price <= '$price';
```

Comment: You need to provide some code or sample so we can help

Comment: joshua which code would you like me to post?

Comment: Your search html and your sql

Comment: Hi Joshua I have updated the code as you have wised.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the order by high or low in your query

```
$qrySearch ="SELECT * FROM Phone WHERE UPPER (Phone_Name) LIKE ('%$search%')
&& Sale_Type = 'Sell' &&  Phone_Price <= '$price'";

$resultp= $con->query($qrySearch) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultp, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                  for ($a = 0; $a < 1; $a++){
                       echo "<div>
                       <h1>".$row['your table column name']."</h1>
                       ".$row ['your table column name']."<br>        
                           </div>"; 
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```